# how to display contact address as the permanent address by clicking the checkbox

Tags: php, jquery

I want to display contact address and permanent address same by clicking the checkbox.
For **eg** : if i type the contact address and click the checkbox then the same address should be displayed in permanent address field. How to do it using jquery?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post some of your code to help us, help you.

Comment: tell us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I have done it via java script. May be this is helpful for all.

Check box code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="present" onclick="permanent(this.form)">
```

Java Script code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function permanent(p) {
        if(p.present.checked == true) {
            p.per_add.value = p.temp_address.value;
            p.per_city.value = p.temp_city.value;
            p.per_state.value = p.temp_state.value;
            p.per_country.value = p.temp_country.value;
            p.per_pin.value = p.temp_pin.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Contact Address

```
<input type="text" id="contact">
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
Contact Address <input type="text" id="permanent">
```

jquery is

```
$('#check').click(function() {
    var c=$('#contact').val();
    $("#permanent").val(c);
});
```

Comment: its not working if i click the text box it doesn't reflect the text

Comment: after typing contact addres click the checkbox

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script>
$('#check').click(function() {
    var c=$('#contact').val();
    $("#permanent").val(c);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="contact">
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
Contact Address <input type="text" id="permanent">
</body>
</html>

Dis s my code but not wrking

Comment: itz working in fiddle bt not wrkg in mine y? any script i have to add?

Comment: if i type something  in 1st textbox after checking itz not displaying in 2nd texbox.

Comment: press f12 and goto console , see its showing any error

Comment: instead of that use this //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
       $('#check').click(function() {

    var c=$('#contact').val();

    $("#permanent").val(c);
});
});


</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
<input type="text" id="contact">
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
Contact Address <input type="text" id="permanent">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function filladd()
{
  if(filltoo.checked == true) 
     {
             var tal11 =document.getElementById("tal").value;
    var dist11 =document.getElementById("dist").value;
    var pin11 =document.getElementById("pin").value;
          

           
            var copytal =tal11 ;
            var copydist =dist11 ;
            var copypin =pin11 ;

            
            document.getElementById("tal1").value = copytal;
            document.getElementById("dist1").value = copydist;
            document.getElementById("pin1").value = copypin;
  }
  else if(filltoo.checked == false)
  {
   document.getElementById("tal1").value='';
   document.getElementById("dist1").value='';
   document.getElementById("pin1").value='';
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Tal</label>
<br/>
<input type="Text" id="tal"  name="Taluka1" class="" placeholder="" >
<br/>
<label>Distic</label>
<br/>
<input type="Text" id="dist" name="Distric1"  placeholder="">  
<br/>
<label>Pincodes</label>
<br/>
<input type="Text" id="pin" name="pincode1"   placeholder="">
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="filltoo" id="filltoo" onclick="filladd()" />Permanent Address same as Current Address   <br/>
<label>Tal</label>
<br/> 
<input type="Text" id="tal1"  name="Taluka1" placeholder="" >
<br/>
<label>Distic</label>
<br/>
<input type="Text" id="dist1" name="Distric1" placeholder="">  
<br/>
<label>Pincodes</label>
<br/>
<input type="Text" id="pin1" name="pincode1"  placeholder="">
<br/>
```

Comment: It's wise to elaborate *why* this code would work when you post it as an answer. This way OP can learn how to do this himself next time.